# Answer the second incoming call/conference

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-conference

I am working with Twilio Voice JS SDK. Every incoming calls are converted to conferences. I can do this.

If there is a second incoming call, I want a user can answer it.

But if I invoke `call.accept()`, the first call will disconnect.

So I tried to hold the first call by update `ParticipantResource.Update()` with `hold = true`. This doesn't help. I listen hold music from browser and the first call is still active.

Is it possible to answer the 2nd incoming call/conference?